# How to terminate ArcMap add-in script?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

I have made an ArcMap add-in which has the condition that only one feature can by selected a computed. If there are more features selected or no feature in the selection, a message will pop up that the script should be terminated. I am using the `sys` module and `sys.exit(0)` in the condition, but this command terminates ArcMap.

Is there something else that terminates only the running Python script, but not ArcMap entirely?

EDIT: I'm using ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: Please read what you have written in your mind.

Comment: I just tried this in 10.4.1 and it didn't shut down my arcmap....

Comment: in 10.2 it does - tested today

Answer (score 4):

That's cool, I didn't know you could shutdown Arc by calling `sys.exit()`.

The in-program python interpreter shuts down with the exit call and since the ArcGIS is depended on it the action shut downs the whole system? Makes sense in this context.

For what you asking, you could wrap your logic in a function and `return None` at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a function and use `return` whenever you wish to terminate the script.

```
def RunScript ():

    #code
    #code code
    #code

    #if selection
    if sel:
        return

    #continue code


RunScript ()
```